# Python Discord Bot | How can i use user inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to make a bot about text-based RPG. And I need a character creation session. But I can't get the user's inputs.

```py
@bot.command()
async def karakterolustur(ctx):
    #Character Name
    await ctx.send("Karakterinin Adı Ne ? ")
    message_response = client.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.user ==ctx.user)
    ad = message_response.content
    print(ad)

    #Character Race
    await ctx.send("Bir Irk Seç [Elf | Cüce | İnsan] : ")
    message_response = client.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.user == ctx.user)
    irk = message_response.content

    #Character Class
    await ctx.send("Bir Sınıf Seç :")
    message_response = client.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.user == ctx.user)
    sinif = message_response.content
    cid = ctx.author.id
```

I wrote this. But it's not working. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `wait_for` is a coroutine, you need to await it
2. You're using `bot.command()` as the decorator, why are you using `client` in `wait_for`? You also need to use `bot` there
3. In all the lambda functions instead of `m.user` use `m.author`. `discord.Message` doesn't have the attribute `user`
4. Also in the lambda functions use instead of `ctx.user` use `ctx.author`

```py
message_response = await bot.wait_for("message", check=lambda m: m.author == ctx.author)
```

Comment: Thank you. I no longer get errors. However, this time it was stuck after the first input. Doesn't give any reaction.

Comment: Yes because you're decorating the command with `bot.command()` and in `wait_for` you're using `client` you need to use `bot` - `await bot.wait_for(...)`